# Migrate Debian to 64 bit and preserve home partition

Tags: 64-bit, debian-wheezy, debian-squeeze

I am currently on Debian Squeeze 32 bit and I want to install Wheezy 64 bit, preserving my /home partition

I know that compiled files will not work unless configuring multiarch, but can I find other issues?

I'm specially concerned about evolution and iceweasel files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, configuration files are architecture indipendent; I've upgraded a similar system some weeks ago: it works flawlessy

Comment: great! do you know what happens with sqlite database files?

Comment: here says sqlite databases are not affected: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.db.pysqlite.user/2327

Comment: sqlite files too are arch-indipendent (firefox history file is a sqlite file, e.g.)

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. If you have installed binary programs in your home directory e.g. in a `/home/user1/bin/` directory, which some users occasionally do then obviously you would have to upgrade that directory as well. Life will be easier since you said you kept a separate `/home` partition.